# How to find out what's preventing a click from happening?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following link on the page:

```
<a href="/go/some/where.htm">...</a>
```

It lives among HTML that makes up a google.maps.InfoWindow box (which itself doesn't have a click event).  This infobox comes up when the user moves the mouse over a mapping pin. For whatever reason, when the user clicks on a link in the infobox, it doesn't fire and I am trying to find out why.

The code base is huge and I have no idea where exactly the preventDefault or propagation is stopped. Is there an easier way?  Can I hook into the event flow some way that would show me what is preventing the click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar situation before, and you have a couple of options.

1. Just search all text through all your code for the term `preventDefault` or similar and check what each one is doing
2. If you're using a modern web browser like Chrome, you can [step through your code.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#stepping)

Comment: I can't step through code that doesn't exist.  It's a link - it doesn't need code.  But there is something that's hooking into it and prevent it.

Comment: @AngryHacker What you're saying doesn't make sense. The only thing that could be "hooking into it" is JavaScript. Nothing else in your web browser will modify the behavior of your HTML except for CSS. Double check that the anchor pointer events aren't being modified: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: I did eventually find it.  Looking for preventDefault and stopPropagation variants proved fruitless.  The problem was that I forgot that returning `false` from an event handler also cancels the event.  And that is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 6):

In addition the JavaScript debugger that Wyatt mentioned, you can check the Event Listener on any DOM element in Chrome Developer Tools. Right-click the element > Inspect: Select the Event Listeners tab on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can right-click the element, select Inspect and then see a list of bound events by clicking the grey mini-button at the end of the element source code.
Then click the event (here: "click") to see the code automatically prettified.

[image: Visual explanation]